# When is an AVL tree better than a hash table?

Tags: performance, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, avl-tree

More specifically, are there any operations that can be performed more efficiently if using an AVL tree rather than a hash table?

Comment: The question is a bit too vague for being exhaustively answered. It greatly depends on the hash table implementation, but lookup operations can very well be much faster in a tree than in a hash table. Also, lookup of several keys with a common prefix are guaranteed to be much faster on any kind of tree than on a hash table (-->processor cache). Insert/remove operations very likely are not more efficient due to the height constraints and the rebalancing, but then again a hashtable might need to do non-trivial operations up to rebuilding the entire hash (-->implementation?), too.

Comment: No.  Unless you consider operations that a hash table just can't support.  Like keeping order and supporting duplicate keys.  Not having to do this is what makes a hash table fundamentally fast.

Comment: Thanks guys, those points are exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if the question was badly worded.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hash tables are not "fundamentally fast", not in general. They fundamentally have O(1) complexity (plus O(N)), but that does not guarantee they are faster in every situation. Especially for large datasets, hash tables are two guaranteed cache misses (more with open addressing, beyond a certain load). A tree, on the other hand, has a reasonable chance of having most if not all nodes in cache, especially when looking up related keys, and needs no final compare. Add to that O(N) time to calculate a hash. It _really_ depends on the implementation, data set, and access pattern.

Comment: "Hash table" is an incomplete solution to start with.  What is the "proper" hash function for the expected keys?  How will hash collisions be handled?  How much (or how little) of all available storage is utilized in worst-case hash collision scenario?  Versus 100% utilization is always possible by AVL tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally prefer AVL trees to hash tables. I know that the expected-time O(1) complexity of hash tables beats the guaranteed-time O(log n) complexity of AVL trees, but in practice constant factors make the two data structures generally competitive, and there are no niggling worries about some unexpected data that evokes bad behavior. Also, I often find that sometime during the maintenance life of a program, in a situation not foreseen when the initial choice of a hash table seemed right, that I need the data in sorted order, so I end up rewriting the program to use an AVL tree instead of a hash table; do that enough times, and you learn that you may as well just start with AVL trees.

If your keys are strings, ternary search tries offer a reasonable alternative to AVL trees or hash tables.

Answer (score -1):

An obvious difference, of course, is that with AVL trees (and other balanced trees), you can have *persistency*: you can insert/remove an element from the tree in O(log N) space-and-time and end up with not just the new tree, but also get to keep the old tree.

With a hash-table, you generally cannot do that in less than O(N) time-and-space.

Another important difference is the operations needed on the keys: AVL tress need a `<=` comparison between keys, whereas hash-tables need an `=` comparison as well as a `hash` function.

Comment: This is not the whole story. Many implementations of persistent hash-table-like structures exist which have logarithmic complexity. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie note this is how clojure and scala implement their default Map types.

Comment: @OscarBoykin: Indeed, HAMTs can be seen as hybrids between hash-tables and binary trees.